# Github Action Assigning Global Environment Variable

Tags: github, github-actions

In Github workflow, to get all the secrets using the below command and assigning it to a variable
To get all the secrets from stored secrets assigned into a variable (based on key (name of the variable) value

```
      run: |
        for keyval in $(grep -E '": [^\{]'  <<< "$SECRETS_CONTEXT" | sed -e 's/: /=/' -e "s/\(\,\)$//"); do
          echo "export $keyval"
          eval export $keyval
        done
```

Output
export "var"=1
export "foo"="bar"
export "x"="test"`

How can I export these variable as a global in Githubworkflow file.
When I defined the steps it's not accessible from other steps.

```
steps:
    - name: Import value
      shell: bash
      run: |
        for keyval in $(grep -E '": [^\{]'  <<< "$SECRETS_CONTEXT" | sed -e 's/: /=/' -e "s/\(\,\)$//"); do
          echo "export $keyval"
          eval export $keyval
        done
```

Github secrets export in workflow

Comment: This will expose your secrets to all the repository users, which would be a huge security flaw. Isn't there another option to extract / get those values?

Comment: I believe not, as the secrets still are not decrypted, they will come like ***** .
Please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 2):

You need to set it to $GITHUB_ENV

```
echo secret=$(value) >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

And it will be available for the duration of the run. When you use `export` it is only set in that tiny scope.